# SetEnv not updating my environment variable (noob warning)

Tags: apache

I am still an Apache noob, and I am trying to set an environment variable that will be used by my Rails application.

I've read https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv and done some google and SO searches. I have at least determined that the value to be assigned must be in quotes. However, when I run `sudo service apache2 restart`, the value of SECRET_KEY_BASE is still not correct (viewed via `printenv`). I don't know what I don't know. Is there some step i'm missing?

In my apache configuration I have:

```
SetEnv SECRET_KEY_BASE "e10e721..."

# Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
DocumentRoot /var/www/some_path
```

Please let me know what other information I might need to share. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few subtle pitfalls here.

First: You can't check it in the terminal you ran that command from. "SetEnv" sets a per-request internal variable that will be copied to CGI-like processes that the server subsequently executes.

Secondly, even if you set a real native environment variable (in e.g. /etc/apache2/envvars) you should not do a `restart` operation since that will not necessarily reload that particular file. You should do a stop and a start.  You still won't see the variable in the command you start the server from, since it was only in the webserver process.

If you want to see the environment of a running process, you can write a basic CGI to dump the environment that was passed down to the CGI script. If you're a PHP user, a basic script with phpinfo() will dump it.

Or, you can determine Apache's process ID with `ps` and then check /proc/$thepid/env (on Linux).